# Can we modify short link created by google url shortner?

Tags: iphone, google-url-shortener

By mistake I have uploaded the application on the App Store without changing the URL for Facebook.

This is the url which is being shared :  goo.gl/7wK2

and it redirects to: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tap-tap-balloon!/id535053777?mt=8

Can we do something so that the same URL (goo.gl/7wK2) will redirect to: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-a-thing/id638627376?mt=8?

Is this possible via the Google URL shortener API or by any other method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not.

You have to create another short url and then republish your application

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do it using tiny.cc. I have used it and was working fine easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not, because the url is derived from what we send to goo * le server.
If you want to change, you must send or submit your new url to goo * le.